# Wrapping and newlines in JEditorPane

Tags: java, newline, word-wrap, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane that is added to a dialog box. The editor pane is used as opposed to JTextArea to handle wrapping and styling. I add some text that has some newlines in it. I expect it to look like this:

```
Line 1 should be like this
Line 2 is too long for a single line and so needs to
    wrap to the next line
Line 3 should be like this
```

But what happens is this:

```
Line 1 should be like this
Line 2 is too long for a single line and so needs to
Line 3 should be like this wrap to the next line
```

Line 2 overlaps with line 3. I can't show it here, but the lines will literally overlap each other.

The text with the newlines (ie: "\n") is returned from a method. I then use editorPane.setText() with that string and call dialog.display().

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `text = text.replaceAll("(\r?\n|\r)", "\r\n");` was my first thought. Though I cannot image that having any influence. Are you using styles (line-height)?

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks! But not sure what you mean. I have a SimpleAttributeSet with some StyleConstants (setFirstLineIndent and setLeftIndent). I can set StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(attrs, x) but that just increases the space between lines, the wrap issue is still present.